# Can I be a resident in two countries at the same time? (UK/Denmark)

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, residency, uk-citizens, denmark

I am a British citizen. I am registered in Denmark as living here, so I am on the registry with an address.

Do I need to de-register from my UK address though? Or can I be registered in both countries?

I didn't de-register before, because originally this was not meant to be a 'permanent' move, and it is most likely temporary (I have some life decisions to make shortly), but obviously because I knew I might be here for more than 3 months at a time, I needed to apply for residency. Plus, brexit happened so if I had left it until the New Year I would not have been able to apply or risk being here longer than 3 months at a time. I realise that when I do end my residency in Denmark, I will not have the same privileged options as before if I want to return in the future.

I have tried googling this question as it seems an obvious one, but I am not getting any answers. Which leads me to believe it is fine?

I don't want to de-register from the UK in case I decide to go home soon, as well as I am thinking of going to University in the UK. What are the rules for all this? Can you be a resident in two countries?

I am currently not paying taxes, as I am currently not earning. I understand it might be different if I was working.

Thank you. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am quite young.

Comment: How does one deregister in the UK?  Which office is responsible for the registration of residents?  Also, why would deregistering in the UK be incompatible with returning home soon?  Couldn't you just reregister when you return?

Comment: Try looking through the topics on https://www.gov.uk/browse/abroad/living-abroad, there may be some that are/could be relevant to your situation

Answer (score 3):

As a UK citizen, with the **right to abode**, you can return to the UK at any time to take up residence.

Important is to insure that your danish residence status is not lost due to an **extensive** absence (often greater than 6 months) from the country.

This is something which you should ask about **beforehand** (at the immigration office where your residence permit will be issued) how to deal with this properly, since it will depend on the local danish laws.

In Germany, you would inform the immigration office of your intention to attend university in the United Kingdom for a specific period and that you intend to return afterwards. They would then confirm this in writing, which means any report they receive that you have 'abandoned' (deregistration) your residence will be ignored.